# " WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception" after installing hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.7 in standalone mode.

Starting the services:

```
Starting namenodes on [hnode1]
hnode1: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-hnode1.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-hnode1.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser- secondarynamenode-hnode1.out

starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-hnode1.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-hnode1.out
```

However, on running a simple mapreduce job from the example docsumentation, gives the following:

```
$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7.jar pi 10 10

WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hduser/QuasiMonteCarlo_1533379418377_2070416414/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2211)
    .
    .
    .
```

I am particularly troubled by this part of the output:
`There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.` in the output. However, `jps` outputs:

```
17795 Jps
15604 DataNode
17350 NameNode
15994 NodeManager
15898 ResourceManager
17548 SecondaryNameNode
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Your jps commands show DN is working but is it reachable?  Have you tried reaching through 50075 port? Is it listening to that port? Because the error is clear that the datanode in inaccessible.

Comment: @Abhinav this is very frustrating but I can no longer reproduce the error now. Thank you anyway. If I manage to reproduce it I will update the question and/or ping you in a comment